# Magento - Customer First/Last name stored as empty in sales_flat_order

Tags: magento, admin

After placed the order, `customer_firstname` and `customer_lastname` stord as `NULL` in `sales_flat_order` table

Also, in admin panel > Sales > Order > View > The customer name displaying as "Guest".

How can we fix this issue or reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Customer placed order as Guest checkout so it display 'Guest' instead of name.

You have to insert his name in Quote when it prepared. or you can achieve it by observer also 
`sales_order_place_before` or `sales_convert_quote_to_order`

```
$quote->setCustomerFirstname($firstname);

$quote->setCustomerLastname($lastname);
```